# PHP File Inclusion Questions

Tags: php, include

I have two php files on two servers. Lets call them server A and server B.

I want my php file on A to include the code in file on B.

What php directives must be enabled on both servers?

Also, when a remote file is included, will the code of the file be included or the output of the code (as in, echo data) sent to the requesting script?

Comment: Your `include()` command will include exactly that payload it gets sent from the questioned server. If that is php code or output depends on the configuration of that server, obviously. Typically it will be output, _unless_ you take very special configuration steps. In general one can say that this approach is a _very_ questionable one. This looks like a _huge_ security issue you open there. Just imagine someone succeeds to fake a reply to an inclusion file: you would execute whatever code Mrs Bad Girl sends you right on your beloved system...

Comment: I believe you can include the file with a `include( 'ftp://user:pass@server.com/file.php' );` if you do not want the parsed data, but it is slow. However you do it, it will be slow. The best solution is to copy the file to the local server!!

Comment: I could simply echo the php code to the calling file. Would that work as text output or will the code be parsed as php code? :S  Also, **what directives need to be set on both servers** for the inclusion to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Server B, you should set, in your php.ini, the value of `allow_url_include` to `On`. Be wary though that there are major security repercussions with using `allow_url_include` so use very carefully and do a lot of due diligence before doing this.

If you want only one directory to allow PHP files to be included by another server, then you can just create an .htaccess file with the following line:

```
php_flag allow_url_include on
```

Whatever your file structure is, then `allow_url_include` is a security concern (unless your server is not accessible to the outside world).

Comment: How can people find out what are the names of php files on my server when I have not even put up an index of my directory online? Also, is it possible for different directories to have different php directives? Or one php installation uses the same directives for all files/folders?

Comment: does this mean I can override the settings in php.ini with htaccess file? Or does it mean that php.ini directive has to be set on **and** then edit the htaccess file?

Comment: It means you can do either. So if you want to have it in a specific directory, then you can just add the line to your .htaccess file without modifying your php.ini

Comment: All right! Where do I need to create .htaccess on my hosting account? As in, in which directory?

Comment: In the directory you wish to include files from. Note that the effect of .htaccess is cascading - which means that any directories within that directory will also have allow_url_include set to on (unless you have another .htaccess in these subdirectories with allow_url_include set to off).

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work for some reason. Anyhow. Thanks for answering. Maybe it's me only and some quirk on my server.